# How can I make this background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, scroll, background-image

When you check this webpage: http://www.google.com/nexus/7/

You see the background image seems like not moving while you scroll.

Is there any JQuery for this?

Comment: youre looking for chromeless video. use html5 video tag. play it programatically. put a div over that with whatever text you want. and youre done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look into Parallax backgrounds.

[A Simple Parallax Scrolling Technique](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/) might be a good starting point.  There are indeed jQuery plugins that can simplify the process, if you wish to use them.

As for actually having a fixed image (as in, a nonmoving background), which is not what I think you want, check out `background-repeat` and `background-attachment: fixed;`.